How to make GoJS tooltips appear only in some nodes?
I started building a graph that shows the approach to anemia as a decision tree. It has some links in the nodes and tooltips on mouse hover in some nodes.
The problem is, it shows an empty tooltip even if hoverText is not defined in the node template, and if it's not defined, it shows the last tooltip text the mouse hovered over.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Approach to Anemia</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/2.1.54/go.js"></script>
    <style>
        #myDiagramDiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiagramDiv"></div>
    <script>
        function init() {
            const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

            const myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
                {
                    initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
                    layout: $(go.TreeLayout, { angle: 90, layerSpacing: 35 })
                });

            myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
                $(go.Node, "Auto",
                    $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { strokeWidth: 2, stroke: "steelblue", fill: "white" }),
                    $(go.TextBlock,
                        {
                            margin: 8,
                            font: "bold 12px sans-serif",
                            isMultiline: false,
                            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit
                        },
                        new go.Binding("text", "name"),
                        new go.Binding("stroke", "url", function(url) { return url ? "blue" : "black"; })),
                    {
                        toolTip: $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
                            $(go.Shape, { fill: "lightyellow" }),
                            $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
                                new go.Binding("text", "hoverText"))
                        ),
                        click: (e, obj) => {
                            const url = obj.part.data.url;
                            if (url) window.open(url, "_blank");
                        }
                    }
                );

            myDiagram.linkTemplate =
                $(go.Link, { routing: go.Link.Orthogonal, corner: 5 },
                    $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 2, stroke: "#ccc" }));

            const nodeDataArray = [
                { key: 1, name: "Anemia", hoverText: "Hgb < 13.2 g/dL men < 11.6 g/dL women" },
                { key: 7, parent: 1, name: "Reticulocytes", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reticulocyte", hoverText: "Determine if the anemia is hypoproliferative or hyperproliferative" },
                { key: 8, parent: 7, name: "Hyperproliferative Anemia", hoverText: "> 2% reticulocytes" },
                { key: 9, parent: 7, name: "Hypoproliferative Anemia", hoverText: "< 2% reticulocytes" },
                { key: 2, parent: 9, name: "Blood count" },
                { key: 3, parent: 2, name: "Iron deficiency", hoverText: "Ferritin < 12 ug/L" },
                { key: 4, parent: 2, name: "Other results" },
                { key: 5, parent: 3, name: "Iron deficiency anemia", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_deficiency_anemia" },
                { key: 6, parent: 4, name: "Other type of anemia" },
                { key: 10, parent: 8, name: "Hemolysis?" },
                { key: 11, parent: 10, name: "No" },
                { key: 12, parent: 11, name: "Bleeding" },
                { key: 13, parent: 10, name: "Yes", hoverText: "LDH\u2191, BU\u2191, Hp\u2193" },
                { key: 14, parent: 13, name: "Blood smear", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_smear" },
                { key: 15, parent: 14, name: "Schistocytes", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schistocyte" },
                { key: 16, parent: 14, name: "Spherocytes / Elliptocytes / Stomatocytes" },
                { key: 17, parent: 14, name: "Thalasemia / Sickle cell" },
                { key: 18, parent: 14, name: "Bite cells" },
                { key: 19, parent: 14, name: "Normal" }
            ];

            myDiagram.model = new go.TreeModel(nodeDataArray);

            myDiagram.toolManager.mouseMoveTools.insertAt(2, $(CustomTooltipTool));
        }

        function CustomTooltipTool() {
            go.Tool.call(this);
        }
        go.Diagram.inherit(CustomTooltipTool, go.Tool);

        init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Kinda worked around it, added a condition on the visibility of the tooltip:
toolTip: $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
    new go.Binding("visible", "hoverText", function(hoverText) { return hoverText != ""}),
    $(go.Shape, { fill: "lightyellow" }),
    $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
         new go.Binding("text", "hoverText"))
    ),

And also had to implicitly set hoverText to "" in thos enodes, otherwise it'd take the value of hoverText from the last node I hovered over (this is the wierd part that makes me feel that it's a workaround and not the right way to do things). For example:
{ key: 2, parent: 9, name: "Blood count", hoverText: ""},

Also I removed the customToolTip stuff at the end of the script, it was redundant.
